# Formula/Mapping of N tri-diagonal matrix into 1D array

Tags: arrays, matrix, mapping, formula, diagonal

[image]
I am looking for the formula to map above matrix into 1D array

There may be 3 orders

1. Row-wise mapping
2. Column-wise mapping
3. Diagonal-wise 1st above diagonal -> 2nd main diagonal -> 3rd below diagonal

Comment: If you want help with your homework, you're going to have to show what you've come up with so far.

Comment: I have found the condition i.e. 
if( i+j >= N-2 and i+j <= N) 
{ return formula}
else {return constant_value}
here formula is unknown.

where i and j are indexes and starting from 0 to N-1